# When exponential map is 1-1 from vector fields to diffeomorphisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, topological-groups

Let $M$ be a connected and complete Riemannian manifold of positive dimension, $k$ be a positive integer, and let $\mathfrak{X}^k_c$ be the set of class $C^k$-vector fields on $M$ of compact support.  It is well known that $Diff_c^k(M)$, the set of class $C^k$ compactly supported homeomorphisms on $M$ is an infinite-dimensional Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{X}_c^k$; with exponential map
$$
Exp:\mathfrak{X}_c^k\ni V \mapsto \operatorname{Solution}\left[\frac{d}{dt} \phi_t(x) = V(\phi_t(p)),\, \phi_0=1_M\right] \in Diff_c^k(M)
$$
and that this map is continuous but not $1-1$ nor onto.  My question is, are the conditions on $M$'s geometry which ensure that $M$ is $1-1$?

Comment: The Riemannian metric is surely irrelevant, as it has no role in the definition of compact sets, vector fields, or the exponential map of a vector field. Every manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric, so this is not a special property of the manifold.

Comment: Yes, I imagined it only has to do with $M$'s topological properties.  I expected if $M$ is contractable then it should be okay, but I'm not certain if this is true nor if its too strong of a condition..

Comment: The image of Exp should consists of the path-connected component of the identity in the diffeomorphism group: 

on the one hand the vector field X gives you a flow connecting the identity to Exp(X), 

on the other hand (up to checking details) a path from Exp(X) to the identity should be realised by a $C^k$-path in the diffeomorphism group (one has to check that this is still true in this infinite-dimensional manifold), which should correspond to a flow by $C^k$-diffeomorphisms, whose time derivative should give a $C^k$-vector field.

Comment: @ThiKu but the time derivative of the flow by $C^k$-diffeomorphisms will probably depend on time

Comment: The map is never surjective, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153484/flows-of-vector-fields-and-diffeomorphisms-isotopic-to-the-identity)

Comment: Yes this follows from Thursten's theorem

Comment: Contractibility is not sufficient, the exponential map is not one-to-one on $\mathbb{R}^n$ whenever $n\ge 2$. Simply consider the vector field of rotations aruond a codimension-$2$ subspace: it generates a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.