# Can orientation preserving diffeomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^d$ be presented by flowmap of dynamical systems?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-topology, differential-equations

Because flowmaps are homeomorphic maps, I was wondering if there is any literature that proves that diffeomorphism $\Phi(x)$ can be expressed as a flowmap of a certain dynamical system?

that is, does there exist $\dot z(t)=v(z(t))$ with initial value $z(0)=x$ such that $\Phi(x)=\phi_v^\tau(x)$ where $\phi_v^\tau(x)=z(\tau)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is usually not possible. There's a [previous MO question discussing this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153484/flows-of-vector-fields-and-diffeomorphisms-isotopic-to-the-identity), but to add to the material there:

- A time-one map $\phi_1$ commutes with the 1-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t$. However, [The C1 generic diffeomorphism has trivial centralizer](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1416) (Bonatti, Crovisier, Wilkinson). So being a time-one map is a rare property, in a sense!
- One very simple obstruction can arise if $\Phi$ has periodic points. For a flow map, a point with period greater than one must correspond to a closed orbit, so the derivative must have at least one eigenvalue of 1. This, too, is a rare property.
- Another set of concrete examples: consider diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which can have complicated chaotic dynamics. For flows in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can't have chaos: recurrence is constrained to be relatively simple, by the Poincare-Bendixson theorem.

Comment: Thanks! But I found a paper that shows diffeomorphism can be approximated by flowmaps, do you have any comments on this paper?  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1474667016448974 

This seems to contradict the chaos you mentioned.

Comment: I believe that paper involves time-varying vector fields, which gives you a lot more freedom.